# Deep cloning Moose object with attributes that are ArrayRef[Object] and Set::Object

Tags: arrays, perl, clone, moose

I've got a [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) object:

```
class My::Game {
  has 'players' => (isa => 'Set::Object', ...)
  has 'action_sequence' => (isa => 'ArrayRef[My::Game::Action]', ...)
}
```

Now I want to be able to clone this object with a call like `$game2 = $game->clone;` How do I deep clone it so that the objects in the ArrayRef are cloned? And more trickily, the [Set::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set::Object)?

I've looked at [MooseX::Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Clone), but I'm unclear how to apply it to this case. Example code would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that simply adding the `MooseX::Clone` role to the class provides a `clone()` method that recursively clones attributes.

- For hashref/arrayref attributes, it copies structures.
- For scalars (including references) it simply does a shallow copy of the reference.
- If you add `traits => ['Clone']` to the attribute, it will recursively clone the attribute by calling `clone()` on the attribute value.

To support cloning `Set::Object`, I ended up creating a trait called `CloneByCoercion` by subclassing the `Clone` trait, parameterized with the type to coerce to/from before cloning.

So to use it, I wrote:

```
has 'blah' => (isa => 'Set::Object', is => rw,
  traits => ['CloneByCoercion' => {to=>'ArrayRef'}]
);
```

`MooseX::Types::Set::Object` provides coercions to and from ArrayRef (although I needed to patch a bug in it: the coercion to ArrayRef should return a reference, not a list)

I also modified `MooseX::Clone` to keep an objects-seen hash, so that it supports cloning interlinked object structures with circular references.

I'll eventually get around to putting this stuff up on CPAN or submitting patches to the modules.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used any of the pieces here ([MooseX::Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aClone), [MooseX::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aCompile), and [Set::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set::Object)), so here's just a rough outline of where I'd start, from my review of the docs and general knowledge of Moose architecture:

- MooseX::Clone gives your object a clone() method, which will then call clone() on each of your attributes with the 'Clone' trait.
- so, you need to add a clone() method to both of your attributes...
- it would be my ambitious *hope* that MooseX::Clone can handle [native attribute arrayrefs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array), but since it probably doesn't, you may get to extend that feature yourself (i.e. if 'action_sequence' has the option `traits => ['Array']`, it is smart enough that the clone method is actually defined via `handles => { clone => [ 'map', 'clone' ] }` -- i.e. clone the attribute by calling clone() on each of the member elements) -- here is likely where you would be submitting your first patch
- [Set::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Set::Object)'s documentation suggests that you can clone objects reliably with [Storable::dclone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) (which you should verify, and flog the author and/or supply patches if this is not correct)
- and now you need to add a clone() method to the Set::Object attribute, which the docs suggest you do with [MooseX::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aCompile) (and here is where you should come on irc.perl.org #moose and give us a blow-by-blow of your progress, so we can make a documentary about it later) :)

Comment: I think you just need to use the `StorableClone` trait on the Set::Object attribute; that should automatically use `dclone` on it.  (StorableClone is part of MooseX::Clone.)